# Woman leaves virtual reality society and is hunted

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Sorry for the lack of details of this post, but I read a short science fiction story about 1-2 months ago and can't for the life of me remember what it is and really want to revisit it.

The plot as I remember it (actual "" labels could be wrong):

It is a story of a person, I think female, who lives in a society where everyone is "plugged in" or wearing headgear that keeps them from seeing the real world. She somehow finds a way to get out of this and experiences the real world. But the system has these policing entities, I think called "watchers" or "scanners", that find and assimilate anyone like her. She however has a "mask" or something to keep them from identifying her. Instead, it lets them thing she is one of them. In the end, she runs into another one of these "watchers" but realizes that it is someone else that has found a way to evade them as well, hinting at a coming uprising.

It feels like it was written in the last 10 years. One more detail: I do remember a line about how she was invisible to everyone else that wasn't "unplugged". She walked around them as she tried to evade one of the "watchers".

Again, sorry for the fluid details. Take anything I said up there with a grain of salt if it even reminds you of anything. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When was "a little while back"? How old was the story? Was it written in English? Any little detail can help! :-)

Comment: I read it about 1-2 months ago. Not certain as the the date of its actual publication, sorry :( It feels like it was written in the last 10 years though.

Comment: One more detail, I do remember a line about how she was invisible to everyone else that wasn't "unplugged". She walked around them as she tried to evade one of the "watchers".